# Variable type for Value Table parameter in Modelbuilder?

Tags: arcpy, modelbuilder, parameters, python-toolbox, multi-values

I've created a python tool with a multivalue input box (parameter type: `GPValueTable`). The box is small and will contain long strings. I'm hoping to be able to add values to the input box with modelbuilder variables. I can't find a variable type which does this.

I tested `String` and it only updated the first box, leaving the rest of the row blank. I also tried clicking the `Multivalue` box when creating the string variable but I could not connect it to the input box afterwards. `Record Set` also did not work.

Is there a variable type which allows me to populate all needed values in a value table parameter? ArcGIS version 10.4.

The model:

[image]

The tool showing the multivalue box:

[image]

The python code for the parameter:

```
    calcs = arcpy.Parameter(
        displayName= "Update Field",
        name= "calcs",
        datatype= "GPValueTable",
        parameterType= "Required",
        direction= "Input")

    letters = string.ascii_uppercase [:numCol]
    calcs.parameterDependencies = ["table"]
    clmns = ["String", "Update Field"]
    clmns = [clmns] + [["String", "Calc Field '{}'".format (a)] for a in letters]
    clmns = clmns + [["String", "Logic Test"], ["String", "Equation"]]
    calcs.columns = clmns
```

Comment: You say _"I'm hoping to be able to add values to the input box with modelbuilder variables"_. In your testing you try one string variable. But looking at your value table it looks like you were going to populate 8 columns? So how were you going to populate your 8 model builder variables? I assume by exposing them as 8 separate inputs? If you are going to do that why bother with the table and just feed your 8 variables into your script?

Comment: @hornbydd The tool is designed for any number of 8-variable inputs. The tool is also designed for end users who don’t know python at all. Some times they’ll use it as a stand alone tool. I’m also interested to see if can also be used in a model and populate the eight variables after reading a table of inputs. It can all be done in python but I think it would be easier for my end users to understand a model.